# Prop being passed but not updating the component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-props

So I have a function called updateAll(data.items) which should take the array and randomly assign a new name, it appears the data.items is updating when I view in vue dev tools and is being passed to the component but not actually updating the browser

I've also added in my buildData.js this is being used for the same app but in react so was trying to keep it as general as I could

```html
//HomeView.vue

<script setup>
import { reactive, watch } from "vue";
import Hero from '@/components/Hero.vue'
import FunctionButton from '@/components/FunctionButton.vue'
import ItemsContainer from '@/components/ItemContainer.vue';
import * as dataFunc from '@/data/buildData'

const data = reactive({
  items: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) || []
})

console.log(data.items)

watch(() => data.items,(newValue) => {
  localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(newValue))
}, {deep: true});


</script>

<template>
    <div class='w-2/3 mx-auto text-center'>
      <Hero HeroText="The one stop shop to store recipes!" />
      <main>
        <h1 class="text-5xl font-extrabold dark:text-white">Recipe Manager</h1>
        <div class='functions gap-4 grid grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 mt-8 mx-auto w-fit'>
          <FunctionButton name="Add new recipe" @click="() => data.items = [...data.items,...dataFunc.buildData(1)]"/>
          <FunctionButton name="Add 100 recipes" @click="() => data.items = [...data.items,...dataFunc.buildData(100)]"/>
          <FunctionButton name="Add 1000 recipes" @click="() => data.items = [...data.items,...dataFunc.buildData(1000)]"/>
          <FunctionButton name="Delete all recipes" @click="() => data.items = dataFunc.deleteAll()"/>
          <FunctionButton name="Edit all recipes" @click="() => data.items = dataFunc.updateAll(data.items)"/>
        </div>
        <ItemsContainer :items="data.items"/>
      </main>
    </div>
</template>
```

```html
//ItemContainer.vue

<script setup>
import Item from '@/components/Item.vue';

const props = defineProps({
  items: {type: Array, default: () => []},
})
</script>

<template>
    <div
        class='items-container w-full md:w-max bg-gray-800 dark:bg-gray-800 text-white dark:text-black mx-auto mt-12 p-4 space-y-4'>
        <Item
          v-for="item in items"
          v-if="items.length > 0"
          :key="item.id"
          :meal="item"
        /> 
        <p v-else class='text-white'>No items to display</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

I tried to make this as generic as possible as trying to make a similar app on Vue and React so they could share this

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

function create(){
    const data = {
        id: uuidv4(), 
        category: category[random(category.length)],
        name: meals[random(meals.length)], 
        prepTime: randomTime(),
        cookTime: randomTime(), 
        isFav: false
    }
    return data
}

function random(max){
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 1000) % max;
}

const meals = [
    "Roast Chicken", "Omelette", "Steak Pie", "Beef Stir Fry", "Fish And Chips", "Tomato And Prawn Risotto", "Pepperoni Pizza", "Cheesy Nachos", "Fajitas", "Baked Potato",
    "Full English Breakfast", "Pancakes", "Chocolate Brownies", "Meatballs With Red Pepper Sauce", "Chicken Cesar Salad", "Beef Burger", "Chips","Macaroni Cheese", "Fillet Steak", "Chicken Wings", 
    "BBQ Ribs", "Tomato Soup", "Prawn Dim Sum", "Pork Gyozas", "Tomato Bruschetta", "Spring Rolls", "Beef Jerky", "Lasagne", "Spagetti Carbonara", "Salmon And Potatoes"
]

const category = [
    "Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner"
]

function randomTime(){
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 30)
}

function buildData(count){
    const data = new Array(count);
    for(let i = 0; i<count; i++){
        data[i] = create();
    }
    return data;
}


function updateAll(currentArray){
    return currentArray.map((item) => {
        return{...item, name: meals[random(meals.length)], }
    })
}

function updateOne(item){
    return{...item, name: meals[random(meals.length)], }
}

function favouriteAll(currentArray = []){
    return currentArray.map((item) => {
        return {...item, isFav: true}
    })
}

function deleteAll(){
    const data = []
    return data;
}

export {buildData, deleteAll, favouriteAll, updateAll, updateOne};
```

Comment: If you don't get a decent answer soon, consider creating and posting a [mre] program that reproduces your problem for us. Please check out the link which explains what this useful tool is and how it can help both you and us. Also, please have a look at the [ask] link which also contains much useful information on how to help make questions easier to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the console for errors.

If I take the functionality from `HomeView.vue`, your `ItemContainer.vue` and an `Item.vue` (which you didn't provided), then it works.

Check the working [Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

The code:

`App.vue`

```
<script setup>
import { ref, watch, reactive } from 'vue'
import ItemsContainer from './ItemContainer.vue';

const data = reactive({
  items: []
})

console.log(data.items)

watch(() => data.items, (newValue) => {
  alert(JSON.stringify(newValue))
}, {deep: true});
  
const addItem = () => {
    data.items.push({ id: data.items.length, name: 'New Item'})
}  
  
</script>

<template>
    <ItemsContainer :items="data.items"/><br />
  <button type="button" @click="addItem()">Add</button>    
</template>
```

`ItemContainer.vue` is the same.

`Item.vue`

```
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  meal: {
    type: Object, 
    default: {undefined}
  }
})
</script>

<template>
    <div>
         {{JSON.stringify(meal)}}<br />
    </div>
</template>
```

### UPDATE

I've updated the [playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) with your functions and it still does work well. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: You're right. But this time the code is about exactly the same.

Comment: So the adding to the reactive object works fine for me but when I try do my updateAll it doesn't appear to keep the reactive state even though when I look at the vue dev tools it looks like the new value prop is being passed.

Comment: I thought I replied also but I've edited my code to show the function for updateAll.  I was trying to use vanilla js so I could use the same code for the same app in react and vue but not sure if I may need to change  this method of thought

Comment: Check the second playground.

Comment: Thanks @Tolbxela, what did you change? Your code looks the same as what I had before?

Comment: *edit, I think it may have been to do with my item component!!** thanks though got it working properly now